# changing index of a gesture recognizer

Tags: iphone, indexing, uigesturerecognizer

I have 6 gesture recognizers each associated with an UIView object inside a ScrollView and I would like to know how to change the index of each view when a gesture is recognized. Should I change the index for each UIView object or can I change index from the recognizer object itself?

Thanks for your response.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "change the index of each view"?  Are you referring to draw order?

Comment: yes. I would like the draw of the associated UIView to be put on foreground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get a gesture, just call

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:gesture.view];
```

Or something along those lines, I don't know your exact hierarchy